# Is it possible to pass raw HTML nodes to Datatables as input data?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) for a simple table on a page. One of the columns contains `select` inputs. When I initialize the Datatables object, I can give it an array of data to populate the table, like so:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({data: arrayOfData});
```

For the moment, I am giving it a string to create the `select` inputs which Datatables (I assume) parses and then places in the cell. However, I know that it is much much faster to create the DOM nodes myself with `document.createElement` than to let jQuery parse some HTML string. When I try to give Datatables a DOM node, all I see is a string in the table like this:

```
[object HTMLSelectElement]
```

Is it possible to give Datatables a raw DOM node?

EDIT:

It seems that I am missing something in my description. Here is my code (anonymized of course). `tableData` is just an array of arrays of mockup data that has HTML similar to the entry I am showing below.

```
var tableData = [['<div class="td_inner_wrapper"><img src="img/drapeaux/fr.svg"></div>', ...], ...]

var myTableDT = $('#myTable').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  data: tableData,
  order: [[1, 'desc'],],
  scrollY: 300,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  searching: false,
  deferRender: true,
  columns: [
    { "title": 'Base', "width": "2.2rem", "className": "dt-center"},
    { "title": 'Date Corresp', "width": "5.8rem", "className": "dt-center"},
    { "title": 'Montant Don', "width": "5.6rem", "type": "num-fmt", "className": "dt-center"},
    { "title": 'Forme Don', "width": "5.7rem", "sortable": false, "className": "dt-center"},
    { "title": 'Type Don', "sortable": false, "className": "dt-center" },
    { "title": 'Réponse', "sortable": false, "className": "dt-center" },
    { "title": 'Date Réponse', "width": "6.3rem", "className": "dt-center"},
    { "title": 'Reçu', "className": "dt-center" },
    { "title": 'Archive', "width": "5rem", "className": "dt-center" },
    { "title": 'Notes', "width": '2.5rem', "className": "dt-center" },
    { "title": 'Date', "className": "dt-center fsize-0p8" }
  ],
  //dom: "frtiS", enable for paging if necessary
  initComplete: function(){
    console.log('init.dt');
  }
});
```

**Edit 2:**

It looks like it's something to do with the content I am giving Datatables. If I give it 100 rows of empty strings, it takes only about 200 ms to generate the table.

Comment: What is your end goal for trying to pass in raw HTML nodes. Do you have an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @EstebanFelix I am trying to speed up the rendering of the Datatables table. Right now, it takes over 250 milliseconds for my table with only 10 rows! And if I substitute the HTML of my `select`s with empty strings, that cuts off 50 millliseconds, so I wonder if the HTML rendering is slowing things down.

Comment: For proof of why generating document nodes directly is much faster, see: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: Yes, it definitely is! I'm just trying to figure out which particular feature you're trying to speed up. Are you saying that the column headers can be `select` elements and that you're trying to speed up the rendering of that? Or are you trying to grab data from a `select` and putting that into Datatables?

Comment: @EstebanFelix What I mean is that there are cells when the content is a `select`. Imagine: `<td><select>...</select></td>`. The inclusion of these cells makes the rendering of the table much much slower especially when there are many rows.

Comment: dataTables are already using `document.createElement` internally when you are adding rows (or initialise upon a DOM table).  There is no option for adding chunks of raw HTML nor fragments.  If you want to speed up dataTables, look at `deferRender`, `autoWidth`, avoid callbacks etc.

Comment: 250 milliseconds for 10 rows sounds remarkably slow based on my experience with datatables. What is actually taking the most time? Is it downloading or communicating with server? Might not be a datatables issue at all.

Comment: @jonmrich I'm not sure what is taking the most time, but I'm not even communicating with the server in this example. I'm giving it a local array pre-populated passed into datatables via the `data` parameter.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, `deferRender` didn't speed things up at all, and I don't have any callbacks, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks again, I was able to shave off about 20% of the time width `autoWidth`, `deferRender`, and `ordering: false`, but it still takes almost 400 ms for 25 rows. Must be something I don't get.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the browser trying to render the images within the table at the same time?

Comment: @jonmrich It's possible. How could I know? At any rate, I think I'm going to just using paging (which I wanted to avoid) because that seems to speed things up enough.